# Selecting data from mysql table and related data from another to join them

Tags: php, mysql

Ive looked at other questions and answers but still dont understand which brings me here.

I have one data base two tables. lets say table1 and table2 from database.

I'm looking to grab all the information from table1 and only one column from table2 that coincides with the correct row in table1.

Example which I know is wrong:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.time_stamp FROM table1, table2 
    WHERE table1.ticket_id=$var AND table1.user_id = table2.user_id
```

Basically select data from table1 then use a value from the selected table to grab the related data from table2 and join them to output them as one mysql_query. Im sure its simple and has been asked before.

edit:

I dont receive an error. SQL just returns noting. log form of this would be:

```
$sqlResults = mysql_query("SELECT table1.* FROM table1 WHERE table1.ticket_id=$var")

while($rowResult = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlResults )) {

$userID = $rowResult['user_id'];

$sqlResults2 = mysql_query("SELECT table2.time_stamp FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.user_id=$userID")

}
```

I want to combine that into one sql statement so i dont have to hit table2 for every row table1 has

Comment: Well this query seems right....what exactly are you looking for???  A better solution?

Comment: Which is the error that you get from MySQL? Also, what's the value of $var? You should probably escape it

Comment: I get no sql return and I'm not worried about escaping the variables since that is not the problem I did not include it. Trying to keep the code clean and to the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` to bind the rows from table2 to those from table1:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.time_stamp FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.ticket_id=$var
```

Comment: In my opinion the best answer. JOINs might be difficult in the beginning, when you understood them you'll never take anything else...

Comment: I tested this and received this error - Not unique table/alias: 'table2'

Comment: check out my edit, when table1 is the same than table2, you need to assign aliases to the tables

Comment: Awesome!!! The issue wasn't your code, just that table1 was the same than table2... You should have said that in your original answer ;)